# Guice - bind interface to the only implementation available

Tags: scala, guice

Is it possible to make Guice bind automatically interface to its implementation if there is only one implementation available?

Most questions I can find is about how to pick one of many implementations available. In my case I have 2 implementations of the interface but at the build time I will make sure only one of them is available.

Answer (score 2):

Guice documentation suggest [@ImplementedBy annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings#implementedby).

Sure, you might think that there is only one available at runtime, but you cannot prevent anyone from adding a JAR to the classpath with another one. So, you need to provide a default yourself.

(Alternatively, you can scan your whole classpath yourself and check if some interface has exactly one implementation and [bind it](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/LinkedBindings). But that is a dangerous assumption IMHO).

Comment: According to me `@ImplementedBy` is an anti-pattern. I mean why on earth will you directly couple the implementation to the interface. that defeats the whole purpose of writing the interface in the first place.

Comment: Are we discussing your preferences or his use case?

Comment: don't assume that his use case necessarily needs `@ImplementedBy`

Comment: His use case requres Guice, separation of interface and implementation, and only one runtime implementation - so a typical situation in Java-land, where you use interfaces instead of a single class, because it is easier to mock and proxy, and only because of that. In such case, if it weren't for testing purposed, yes, writing an interface and tying it to class would be redundant. But since he hasn't migrated from Guice, I guess that he hasn't migrated from typical Java patterns as well, so he might use typical Java solution.

Comment: `@ImplementedBy` doesn't really solve my problem, it just different way of calling bind and it adds a compile-time dependency from the interface to its implementation. Unless we had preprocess but thats not C++. I was afraid that the answer will be, it is not possible, but asked it just for confirmation. I was hoping that Guice has a feature for searching a classpath as you suggested.

Comment: @Gustek "Scanning the classpath" can mean one of two things: Iterate over loaded classes and check the interfaces, or loading or parsing all classes on the classpath to check the interfaces. It should be clear what the problem with both approaches is. For the same reason OSGi and similar frameworks require you to provide metadata to tell them which interfaces you extend, instead of them checking every class.